# Ajax request always returning true

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have the following AJAX script, but for some reason it's not returning false so the form can continue; it always returns true.

```
<form action="check.html" onsubmit="return LoginValidation()" method="post"> 

    function LoginValidation(){  
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;   
    var password = document.getElementById("pass1").value;   
    var errormsg = document.getElementsByClassName("error-msg");   
    var userError = document.getElementsByClassName("userError");    

    var req;
    if(username!="" && password!=""){
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();        
        req.onreadystatechange = function(){            
            if(req.readyState==4 && req.status==200){
                var returntxt = req.responseText;
                if(returntxt.length=="20"){
                    alert("working");
                }
                else{                    
                    alert("not working");
                    return false;
                 }
            }            
        };
        req.open("POST","LoginCntrl",true);
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        req.send("username="+username+"&password="+password);

    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Ajay, looks like you are mixing JavaScript and HTML.

Comment: no i'm doing in a proper way like different file for js and html.

Comment: You will have to put it in the form of a jsFiddle.

Comment: can you please explain me actually i don't know much more about js i'm a java student

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slight different with JS listener.  Also, is there an issue with what you are getting back from you AJAX call when you actually submit data ?  You have 'alert("not working")' in the response handler.  What are you actually getting back in returntxt ?

HTML

```
<form id = "validationform"> 
<input id="username" name="username">
<input id="pass1" name="pass1">
<input type="submit" style="display:none"/>
<span class="error-msg"></span>
<span class="userError"></span>
</form>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("validationform").addEventListener("submit", function(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;   
    var password = document.getElementById("pass1").value;   
    var errormsg = document.getElementsByClassName("error-msg");   
    var userError = document.getElementsByClassName("userError");    


    var req;

    if(username !="" && password !=""){
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();        
        req.onreadystatechange = function(){            
            if(req.readyState==4 && req.status==200){
                var returntxt = req.responseText;
                if(returntxt.length=="20"){
                    alert("working");
                }
                else{                    
                    alert("not working");
                    return false;
                 }
            }            
        };
        req.open("POST","LoginCntrl",true);
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        req.send("username="+username+"&password="+password);

    }
    else {
    this.querySelector(".error-msg").innerHTML = "Please enter username and password";
        //return false;
    }
});
```

You might want to get a https://jsfiddle.net or https://codepen.io/ account.

Comment: sir how to redirect user to another page if login details are correct.

Comment: i am just validating username and password are correct or not.if correct then they simply redirect to another page like user home page